# Debugging a Xamarin App on iPhone from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a basic hello world set up. It contains a PCL project and an iOS project. The build host is connected and my iPhone 5 is connected to my mac.

I would like to debug from Visual Studio directly to my iPhone, but I can't get Visual Studio to recognize the device. It says "No Devices Detected".

I'm running the Xamarin trial with Visual Studio 13.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You must have an Apple Developer License in order to deploy to devices.  You will have to do the deployment from an Apple computer, even though you have Visual Studio running the deployment.  You'll have to make sure that the Apple computer is running the Xamarin Host.